# How does Grabby Hand work?

Tags: peglin

The description for the Grabby Hand relic states:

> Flying enemies are attacked horizontally, allowing for improved targeting

What does "attacked horizontally" mean? How does Grabby Hand improve targeting?

[image: Grabby Hand description]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find a screenshot of the applicable situation right now, so permit me some ASCII art. `P` is Peglin, `o` is a slime, and `x` is a bat.

```
                      x        x
 P       o        o       o
```

Under normal circumstances the ball is thrown from Peglin to the targeted enemy, and hits the first enemy it encounters. Thus, in the situation above, you cannot hit any of the bats because the first slime is in the way.

With Grabby Hand, the ball is instead thrown horizontally from the left of the screen, so you can hit the first bat if you target it.

```
      x        x
 P        o
```

There's also a synergy with piercing attacks. In the situation above, you could only hit the first bat, because the piercing shot would continue diagonally upwards. If you have the Grabby Hand, it will instead hit both bats if you target the first one.

Comment: Ah, so instead of firing in a diagonal line originating from Peglin, it fires in a straight horizontal line.